# Hide and Open Columns in MS Project Gannt Chart using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have been searching the internet and testing, without much success, how to hide all task fields and then open targeted task fields in the Gannt Chart view of ms project. I am doing this because I want my script to automate the formatting, so the end-user does not have to pull up the fields that have interacted with the macro.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: BP130, I'd use the ViewEdit and TableEditEx Methods. You might want to incorporate this into a Project_Open Event so it's done automatically when the user opens the file.

Comment: @john-project, I learned after this post through trial and error that you can save table types. Once a table is saved, you could toggle to it using view/tables. The saved table will automatically close all visible fields and open to the ones you want.